# Change the URL also when changing the content of DIV with JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to achieve something like Facebook, where the top bar stays there and only the content underneath it changes for different pages. At the same time the URL at the top also changes, for example /messages or /events.

I'm not completely sure if this is how Facebook works but I'm trying to achieve something like this... Right now I can't figure out how this could be done...

Does anyone know how this could be achieved or if there is a name for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a fixed header that is on all of your current pages, so that whenever a new page loads it appears the header is still there, or you could do the more complex way of putting all your pages in separate divs on one page, and hiding/showing the appropriate divs when a link is clicked. I'd recommend the first way personally, but those are some options.
I'm sure there are other ways to go about this.

If that isn't what you want then I apologize.

Edit: Also, my first suggestion will load a whole new page, so if you want the seamless transition effect then the second option will be the better route to go

Comment: Alright I'll go with the first one. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Can you load these DIVs with ajax or no need to/that's not what ajax is used for?

Comment: you could load them with Ajax but you don't have to. If you just want one document, then place them all in the separate divs

Answer (score 0):

Templates perhaps? You can't change urls without navigating to a different page as far as I know. If you want consistent elements on the page with varying content that basically is the function of templates.

If you're looking for dynamic elements to show up on the page then you should look into AJAX and DOM manipulation. jQuery is the defacto library to help with both of those. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/ and maybe search for a template engine. Most web frameworks include a template system to create consistent styles and allow code reuse.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use #anchors, that won't reload the page. For newer browsers, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history to update the url without reloading the page

Comment: You don't need jQuery just `window.location = '#myHashUrl'` or `history.pushState()`